# Cordova overwrites Framework 7 custom JS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have followed the procedures outlined here in the Framework7 [documentation](https://cdn.framework7.io/docs/installation) to build a PWA with cordova. I'm on Ubuntu. Something happens when I cd my projects and run cordova in the browser. The cordova.js overwrites any html or custom js and I'm stuck here. If I remove cordova.js from the project, then I can use custom F7 js and css. Thing is, I'm building a Hybrid app for Android and Apple so I do need the cordova plugins and without cordova.js well this wont happen. Is this a catch 22 what's going on? I've built hybrid cordova apps before and this never happened.

**structure of folders**
[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!--app title-->
<title>MyApp | F7 Cordova App </title>
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library Bundle CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.bundle.min.css">
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library Bundle JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!--custom stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<!--JQUERY UI CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<!--JQUERY-->
<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<!--JQUERY UI JS-->
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- App root element -->
<div id="app">
<!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
<div class="view view-main">
<!-- Initial Page, "data-name" contains page name -->
<div data-name="home" class="page">

<!-- Top Navbar -->
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-bg"></div>
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="title">Awesome App</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Bottom Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom">
<div class="toolbar-inner">
<!-- Toolbar links -->
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Scrollable page content -->
<div class="page-content">
<p>Page content goes here</p>
<!-- Link to another page -->
<a href="/about/">About app</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<!--scripts-->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about this wrong. I treated Framework7 just like any other regular framework (ie : mobileui). It's a little different workaround if you want to make it work with cordova. I did with the framework-ui, it's best to just brute force with the framework-cli.

1. Install Framework7-Cli

   npm install framework7-cli -g
2. Install Cordova

   npm install cordova -g
3. Create project directory

   mkdir myapp
4. Enter directory

   cd myapp
5. Run Framework7-cli

   framework7 create

Framework 7 CLI will ask you questions on how it should setup your app.
pick the following options:

```
1. Cordova app (target native iOS and Android).
2. Enter any name you would like to then enter
3. Just click enter on the App package (Bundle ID).
4. Pick Framework7 Core.
5. Tabbed Views.
6. No bundler.
7. No, use default color theme.
8. Yes, include icon fonts.
Let it work and finish...
```

6. Install http-serve in your myapp directory

   npm install http-serve -g
7. Previewing the app in the browser

> cd myapp/www

```
http-serve
```

8. NPM will give you 3 different addresses to see your F7 project

   http://127.0.0.1:8080

   http://192.168.0.101:8080

   http://192.168.44.56:8080

To compile your Cordova app

```
npm run build-cordova-android
```

or

```
npm run build-cordova-ios
```